# Перенос в слове "кресло-диван"?

Tags: орфография, перенос

Как правильно сделать перенос в слове "кресло-диван"?

Answer (score 2):

Крес-ло-ди-ван\ кре-сло-ди-ван

Answer (score 2):

Можете смело разрывать в месте дефиса. Дефис остаётся на первой строке, на второй не дублируется, дополнительного знака переноса при этом не ставится (даже если при верстке для дефиса и переноса используются графически разные символы).    
Раньше на этот счет существовали разные рекомендации: то запрещали, то требовали повтора на второй строке, сейчас всё сильно упростилось. Разумеется, осталась и возможность переноса с разрывом внутри составляющих: *крес-//ло-кровать, кресло-//кровать, кресло-кро-//вать, кре-//сло-кровать*. Последний вариант наименее предпочтителен.

Comment: Интересно, что хотел сказать минусящий?!  
Хоть бы пояснения давали.